# jQuery get value within child div

Tags: jquery

I need to grab the text value of a child div.

```
<div id='first'>
    <div id='first_child'>A</div>
    <div id='second_child'>B</div>
    <div id='third_child'>C</div>
</div>
```

I am trying to grab the value B. I am currently trying this but it is not working,

```
var text_val = $('#first').next('#second_child').val();
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You want to use `children()` and `text()` instead of `val()`.  Although, since what you are selecting has an id (and ids must be unique), you could also simply select based on the id without involving the container element at all.

The `val()` method only works on input elements, textareas, and selects -- basically all form elements that contain data.  To get the textual contents of a container, you need to use `text()` (or `html()`, if you want the mark up as well).

```
var text_val = $('#second_child').text(); //preferred
```

or

```
var text_val = $('#first').children('#second_child').text(); // yours, corrected
```

Comment: The JQuery docs indicate that nextAll traverses siblings, not children.

Comment: @John - you're absolutely correct.  I didn't read the HTML and query closely enough.  I've updated to indicate that `children()` is needed instead of `next()` -- though both are unnecessary since the id-based selector is better anyway.

Answer (score 7):

next() and nextAll() traverse the *siblings* of the element, not the children.  Instead, use "find()"

```
var text_val = $('#first').find('#second_child').html();
```

You use val() when dealing with elements like inputs and textareas.  html() will return whatever is under the div (which works in your example).  text() will return the text in the element (wich would also work in your example).

Your example also makes me suspicious of your design.  If you have multiple ids set to "#second_child", your html is confused.  Instead, use a class.  However, if there's only one id "#second_child", then all you need is:

```
var text_val = $('#second_child').text();
```

Answer (score 6):

you can simply:

```
var text_val = $('#second_child').text();
```

as pointed by previous answers. but, since you "need to grab the text value of a child div", i assume that the child div id probably not always available. you can try this instead:

```
var text_val = $('#first').children().eq(1).text();
```

where 1 is the index of the child div (since it count starts from zero)

Answer (score 4):

Try this...

```
var text_val = $('#first > #second_child').text();
```

Answer (score 4):

Simple,

```
var text_val = $('#second_child').text();
```

Or your change,

```
var text_val = $('#first').children('#second_child').text();
```

This will return "B" from div of id "second_child"

**UPDATE** Changed the second solution to `children()` instead of `nextAll()`.

Comment: The JQuery docs indicate that nextAll traverses siblings, not children.

Comment: Sweet, thanks for pointing this out, I'll switch to `children()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

For multiple elements with the same id:

```
var text_val = $('#first').children('#second_child').text();
```

For a single element with a particular id:

```
var text_val = $('#second_child').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

........

```
var text_val = $('#first').children('#second_child').text();
```

Comment: The JQuery docs indicate that nextAll traverses siblings, not children.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to go into lists, use this:

`jQuery('.first > ul > li:nth-child(6)').text();`

Example code gets the value of the 6th item in a list.