# How to get content of a child div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why this doesn't work:

```
<div class="store" id="vframestore">
    <div>http://www.youtube.com/embed/_6DPBCOukLU?showinfo=0&modestbranding=1&fs=0&rel=0</div>
    <div>http://www.youtube.com/embed/ZMr0q4Jz_uM?showinfo=0&modestbranding=1&fs=0&rel=0</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var a = $("#vframestore").children[0].html;
console.log(a);
```

> error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'html' of undefined

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery get value within child div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312876/jquery-get-value-within-child-div)

Comment: `var a = $("#vframestore").children()[0];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like following.

```
var a = $("#vframestore").children().first().html();
```

Or

```
var a = $("#vframestore div").eq(0).html();
```

Answer (score 0):

With vanilla JS:

```
document.querySelector('#vframestore > DIV').innerHTML
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a CSS selector?

```
var a = $("#vframestore div:first-child").html();
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var parent = document.getElementById("vframestore");
var child = parent.children[0].innerHTML;
//alert(child);
console.log(child);
```

```html
<div class="store" id="vframestore">
  <div>http://www.youtube.com/embed/_6DPBCOukLU?showinfo=0&modestbranding=1&fs=0&rel=0</div>
  <div>http://www.youtube.com/embed/ZMr0q4Jz_uM?showinfo=0&modestbranding=1&fs=0&rel=1</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery's `eq()` for getting required child div and `.html()` for getting child div content.

[Jquery's .eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

[Jquery's .html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var childDiv1 = $('#vframestore div').eq(0).html();
  var childDiv2 = $('#vframestore div').eq(1).html();

  // alert child div contents
  alert(childDiv1);
  alert(childDiv2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="store" id="vframestore">
  <div>http://www.youtube.com/embed/_6DPBCOukLU?showinfo=0&modestbranding=1&fs=0&rel=0</div>
  <div>http://www.youtube.com/embed/ZMr0q4Jz_uM?showinfo=0&modestbranding=1&fs=0&rel=0</div>
</div>
```